# Не прогружаются некоторые картинки

Tags: css, css3

Когда запускаю сайт на локальном сервере, он полностью прогружается, все картинки видны и всё стоит на своих местах:
[image]
Когда просто тыкаю по index.html:
[image]
В чем может быть проблема и как это исправить?!

загрузил сайт на хаб: http://avoska.github.io/metall/

Answer (score 1):

Есть принципиальная разница в относительных и абсолютных путях.
`src="img"` -- относительный, `src="/img"` -- абсолютный.

При открытии локально корень абсолютного пути находится на диске D:, поэтому ничего и не работает. А на сайте корень находится тут: http://avoska.github.io/. Поэтому опять же картинки не прогружаются.